# Unable to solve the XOR problem with just two hidden neurons in Python

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I have a small, 3 layer, neural network with two input neurons, two hidden neurons and one output neuron. I am trying to stick to the below format of using only 2 hidden neurons.

[image]

I am trying to show how this can be used to behave as the XOR logic gate, however with just two hidden neurons I get the following poor output after 1,000,000 iterations!

```
Input: 0 0   Output:  [0.01039096]
Input: 1 0   Output:  [0.93708829]
Input: 0 1   Output:  [0.93599738]
Input: 1 1   Output:  [0.51917667]
```

If I use three hidden neurons I get a much better output with 100,000 iterations:

```
Input: 0 0   Output:  [0.01831612]
Input: 1 0   Output:  [0.98558057]
Input: 0 1   Output:  [0.98567602]
Input: 1 1   Output:  [0.02007876]
```

I am getting a decent output with 3 neurons in the hidden layer but not with two neurons in the hidden layer. Why?

As per a comment below, this [repo](https://github.com/ashish-ucsb/xor_back_propagation) contains code of high to solve the XOR problem using **two** hidden neurons.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions are appreciated!
Attached is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# Sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


alpha = [0.7]

# Input dataset
X = np.array([[0, 0],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 1]])

# Output dataset
y = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T

# seed random numbers to make calculation deterministic
np.random.seed(1)

# initialise weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((2, 3)) - 1  # 1st layer of weights synapse 0 connecting L0 to L1
syn1 = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1  # 2nd layer of weights synapse 0 connecting L1 to L2

# Randomize inputs for stochastic gradient descent
data = np.hstack((X, y))    # append Input and output dataset
np.random.shuffle(data)     # shuffle
x, y = np.array_split(data, 2, 1)    # Split along vertical(1) axis

for iter in range(100000):
    for i in range(4):
        # forward prop
        layer0 = x[i]  # Input layer
        layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, syn0))  # Prediction step for layer 1
        layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1, syn1))  # Prediction step for layer 2

        layer2_error = y[i] - layer2  # Compare how well layer2's guess was with input

        layer2_delta = layer2_error * sigmoid(layer2, deriv=True)  # Error weighted derivative step

        if iter % 10000 == 0:
            print("Error: ", str(np.mean(np.abs(layer2_error))))
            plt.plot(iter, layer2_error, 'ro')


        # Uses "confidence weighted error" from l2 to establish an error for l1
        layer1_error = layer2_delta.dot(syn1.T)

        layer1_delta = layer1_error * sigmoid(layer1, deriv=True)  # Error weighted derivative step

        # Since SGD we need to dot product two 1D arrays. This is how.
        syn1 += (alpha * np.dot(layer1[:, None], layer2_delta[None, :]))  # Update weights
        syn0 += (alpha * np.dot(layer0[:, None], layer1_delta[None, :]))

    # Training was done above, below we re run to test algorithm

    layer0 = X  # Input layer
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, syn0))  # Prediction step for layer 1
    layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1, syn1))  # Prediction step for layer 2


plt.show()
print("output after training: \n")
print("Input: 0 0 \t Output: ", layer2[0])
print("Input: 1 0 \t Output: ", layer2[1])
print("Input: 0 1 \t Output: ", layer2[2])
print("Input: 1 1 \t Output: ", layer2[3])
```

Comment: You already have answer in your question. If you only have one layer, it just is a linear classification. If you have two layer, it is kind of a linear classification. The more layer you have, the more capacity your net has. (My shallow understanding). By the way, good question!

Comment: @Zhengfang Xin, thank you for your comment. But in my question I state that I always have 3 layers (1 input, 1 hidden and 1 output). My question is about how many neurons in the hidden layer. I am getting a decent output with 3 neurons in the hidden layer but not with two neurons in the hidden layer. Why?

Comment: Maybe this TR could offer some insight: http://yen.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/techreps/pdf/TR148.pdf?

Comment: I cannot post a comment yet (so, this answer is a comment) Refer to this [repo](https://github.com/ashish-ucsb/xor_back_propagation), where I've tried to explain XOR with 2 hidden neurons in detail with plots and equations, it also has notebook for the code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that you have not considered any `bias` for the neurons.
You have only used weights to try and fit the `XOR` model.

Incase of 2 neurons in the hidden layer, the network under-fits as it can't compensate for the bias.

When you use 3 neurons in the hidden layer, the extra neuron counters the effect caused due to the lack of bias.

This is an example of a network for XOR gate. You'll notice `theta` (bias) added to the hidden layers. This gives the network an additional parameter to tweak.

[image]

[Additional resources](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/effect-of-bias-in-neural-network/)

Comment: As per a comment below, the repo linked to contains code of high to solve the XOR problem using **two** hidden neurons.

Answer (score 2):

It is an unsolvable equation system, that is why NN can not solve it either.
While it may be an oversimplification, if we say the transfer function is linear, the expression becomes something like

```
z = (w1*x+w2*y)*w3 + (w4*x+w5*y)*w6
```

Then there are the 4 cases:

```
xy=00, z=0 = 0
xy=10, z=1 = w1*w3+w4*w6
xy=01, z=1 = w2*w3+w5*w6
xy=11, z=0 = (w1+w2)*w3 + (w4+w5)*w6
```

The problem is that

```
0 = (w1+w2)*w3 + (w4+w5)*w6 = w1*w3+w2*w3 + w4*w6+w5*w6            <-- xy=11 line
                            = w1*w3+w4*w6 + w2*w3+w5*w6 = 1+1 = 2  <-- xy=10 and xy=01 lines
```

So the seemingly 6 degrees of freedom are just not enough here, that is why you experience the need for adding something extra.

Comment: As per a comment below, the repo linked to contains code of high to solve the XOR problem using **two** hidden neurons.